# D programming error

Tags: d

i can't get my program to work because of srand. Please help. I wrote my program in C++ but transitioning it to D. I don't understand how srand works in D.

main.d(18): Error: function core.stdc.stdlib.srand (uint seed) is not callable using argument types (long)

```
import std.stdio;
import std.random;
import core.stdc.time;
import core.stdc.stdlib;


int criminals[8];
int a[8];
int b[8];
int c[8];
int countA,countB,countC;
int loserCount = 0;
int p1,p2,p3;

void main(string[] args)
{

srand(time(null));
int p1 = rand() % 7;
p1++;
int temp = rand() % 7;
while(temp+1 == p1)
{
    temp = rand() % 7;
}
p2 = temp+1;
temp = rand() % 7;
while(temp+1 == p1 || temp+1 == p2)
{
    temp = rand() % 7;
}
p3 = temp+1;
//writefln("criminals: ", p1, " ", p2," ", p3);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
{
    if(i == p1 || i == p2 || i == p3)
        criminals[i] = 1;
    else
        criminals[i] = 0;
    a[i] = 0;
    b[i] = 0;
    c[i] = 0;
}

writefln("\nLets Start the game. There are 7 criminals: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 out of which 3 are the real perpetrators.");

while(true)
{

    writefln("3 random criminals: ");
    int p1 = rand() % 7;
    p1++;
    int temp2 = rand() % 7;
    while(temp2 + 1 == p1)
    {
        temp2 = rand() % 7;
    }
    p2 = temp2+1;
    temp2 = rand() % 7;
    while(temp2+1 == p1 || temp2+1 == p2)
    {
        temp2 = rand() % 7;
    }
    p3 = temp2+1;

    writefln(" ", p1, p2, p3);

    int tempCount = 0;
    if(criminals[p1] == 1)
        tempCount++;
    if(criminals[p2] == 1)
        tempCount++;
    if(criminals[p3] == 1)
        tempCount++;
    writefln("Out of these ", tempCount, " are real perpetrators");
    writefln("Does any player want to guess? (Y/N)");
    char ans;
    while(true)
    {

        if(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
        {
            if(countA > -1)
            {
                writefln("Player 1 choice: ");
                int tempA;
                //cin>>tempA;
                if(criminals[tempA] && a[tempA] == 0)
                {
                    a[tempA] = 1;
                    countA++;
                }
                else if(criminals[tempA] == 0)
                {
                    countA = -1;
                    loserCount++;
                }
            }
            if(countB > -1)
            {
                writefln("Player 2 choice: ");
                int tempB;
                //cin>>tempB;
                if(criminals[tempB] && b[tempB] == 0)
                {
                    a[tempB] = 1;
                    countB++;
                }
                else if(criminals[tempB] == 0)
                {
                    countB = -1;
                    loserCount++;
                }
            }
            if(countC > -1)
            {
                writefln("Player 3 choice: ");
                int tempC;
                //cin>>tempC;
                if(criminals[tempC] && c[tempC] == 0)
                {
                    a[tempC] = 1;
                    countC++;
                }
                else if(criminals[tempC] == 0)
                {
                    countC = -1;
                    loserCount++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(ans == 'N' || ans == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            writefln("Wrong Input!!");
    }
    if(countA == -1)
        writefln("Player 1 has LOST");
    if(countB == -1)
        writefln("Player 2 has LOST");
    if(countC == -1)
        writefln("Player 3 has LOST");
    if(loserCount == 3)
    {
        writefln("\nAll Players have LOST\n\nGAME ENDS!");
        break;
    }
    if(countA == 3)
    {
        writefln("Player 1 WINS!!");
    }
    if(countB == 3)
    {
        writefln("Player 2 WINS!!");
    }
    if(countC == 3)
    {
        writefln("Player 3 WINS!!");
    }
    if(countA == 3 || countB == 3 || countC == 3)
    {
        writefln("GAME ENDS!!");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

when i tried to compile on DMD...it gav me this msg: "OPTLINK: Error 3: Cannot Create File crimGame.exe"

Answer (score 2):

The error message means in `srand(time(null));` srand wants a uint (32 bit) integer as argument but `time` returns a long (64 bit). You would need to cast it to a uint:

```
srand(cast(uint) time(null));
```

However before you do this you should also try compiling in 64 bit mode. If it works then without modification, change the cast to `cast(size_t)` because then its dependent on the target architecture.

Also instead of using `srand` and `rand` you should use `uniform` from `std.random`, it's the random function in D. You don't even need to set a seed then because it will take some unpredictable value (like time, process id, thread id, etc) as seed automatically.

You would then replace your `rand() % 7` calls with `uniform(0, 7)` (which generates a random value from 0-6 because it won't include 7. It will also only generate whole numbers because both arguments are integers and not floating point values)

Comment: thank you. when i tried to compile on DMD...it gav me this msg: 
"OPTLINK: Error 3: Cannot Create File crimGame.exe"

Comment: Visual Studio installed? Write permissions in that folder? Folder path name not longer than ~200 characters? What command are you using to compile?

Answer (score 0):

srand() needs an unsigned integer (32-bit) argument but time() returns long (64-bit)